# Implement subresouce integrity (SRI) for analytics.js (google-analytics) Mozilla Obersvatory

Tags: javascript, security, google-analytics, content-security-policy, subresource-integrity

### Background

I have a site which uses Google analytics, like

```
<script 
   src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"/>
```

and use Mozilla Observatory to test it for security flaws.

### Problem

I have the following problem from Mozilla Observatory:

> Subresource Integrity (SRI) not implemented, but all external scripts are loaded over HTTPS

### Thoughts so far

It doesn't seem to be possible to create a hash for it, like via https://www.srihash.org/. And I don't want to create the hash locally because if `analytics.js` changes, it'll break the site.

I could use a `nonce` but I'm not sure how I would generate this with each request.

I was considering downloading `analytics.js` and using it locally instead. Are there any downsides to doing this?

*Thanks in advance*